# Easy Question is there a better way to store JSON values as an Array than the way I am? Code Included

Tags: ajax, arrays, json

Here is my method to this:

```
<script>
function games(){

document.write("loading");

$.ajax({
    url: "http://allencoded.com/test3.php",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

    var homeTeams = new Array();

    for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
        homeTeams[i]=data.gms[i].h }


     }
});

}
</script>
```

While it works fine. I am just looking for an easier way to do this if it is possible.

Comment: One refinement: the Array Literal syntax is [preferred](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767), instead of  `var homeTeams = new Array();`, use `var homeTeams = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the $.ajax call; since you're using jQuery, you could do this as well:

```
var homeTeams = [];
data.gms.each(function(index, element) {
  homeTeams.push(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer browsers, you can use
[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var homeTeams = data.gms.map(function (team) { return team.h; });
```

In older brosers, your approach is fine. Still, using `push()` may be more performant:

```
var homeTeams = [];

for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
    homeTeams.push(data.gms[i].h);
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well go with [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)